# Replace elements in nested quoted lists adds new elements?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a nested list, and I am trying to non-destructively replace all its elements (inside the nested list as well).  That is, given my input list

```
'(1 '(2 3 4) '(5 6 7) 8 9)
```

I am trying to achieve

```
'(0 '(0 0 0) '(0 0 0) 0 0)
```

I tried the following

```
 (defun subs-list (list value)
  "Replaces all elements of a list of list with given value"
  (loop for elt in list
       collect (if (listp elt)
           (subs-list elt value) 
           value)))
```

But when I try

```
(subs-list '(1 '(2 3 4) '(5 6 7) 8 9) 0)
(0 (0 (0 0 0)) (0 (0 0 0)) 0 0)
```

is the output I get. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you really sure `'(1 '(2 3 4) '(5 6 7) 8 9)` is a useful list? I have never seen such a list in practical applications in Lisp. Nested quoted lists usually don't make any sense and are an indicator for a wrong understanding of *quoting* in Lisp.

Comment: @RainerJoswig, you're right, I initially was made to believe that ' was short for (list). My actual input is `(list 1 (list 2 3 4) (list 5 6 7) 8 9)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24370843/1281433) and [wdebeaum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24370892/1281433) explain why you're getting the results that you're getting;  the nested quotes mean you've actually got a list like `(1 (quote (2 3 4)) (quote (5 6 7)) 8 9)`, and you're replacing the symbol `quote` with `0`, and that's why you get `(0 (0 (0 0 0)) (0 (0 0 0)) 0 0)`.  You probably want just `'(1 (2 3 4) (5 6 7) 8 9)` with no nested quotes.

It's worth pointing out that Common Lisp already provides a functions for non-destructively substituting in cons-trees, though:  [subst](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm#subst), [subst-if](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm#subst), and [subst-if-not](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm#subst).  There are destructive versions, too: [nsubst](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm#subst), [nsubst-if](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm#subst), and [nsubst-if-not](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_substc.htm#subst).  In particular, for this case you can just replace everything that's *not* a list with 0, either by using the [complement](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_comple.htm) function with listp and subst-if, or using listp and subst-if-not:

```
;; With `extra' elements because of the quotes:

(subst-if-not 0 #'listp '(1 '(2 3 4) '(5 6 7) 8 9))
;=> (0 (0 (0 0 0)) (0 (0 0 0)) 0 0) 

(subst-if 0 (complement #'listp) '(1 '(2 3 4) '(5 6 7) 8 9))
;=> (0 (0 (0 0 0)) (0 (0 0 0)) 0 0)
```

```
;; With no `extra' elements:

(subst-if-not 0 #'listp '(1 (2 3 4) (5 6 7) 8 9))
;=> (0 (0 0 0) (0 0 0) 0 0)

(subst-if 0 (complement #'listp) '(1 (2 3 4) (5 6 7) 8 9))
;=> (0 (0 0 0) (0 0 0) 0 0)
```

If you wanted to take the hybrid approach suggested in [wdebeaum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24370892/1281433) where you don't replace quotes, you can do that do:

```
(subst-if 0 (lambda (x)
              (not (or (listp x)
                       (eq 'quote x))))
          '(1 '(2 3 4) '(5 6 7) 8 9))
;=> (0 '(0 0 0) '(0 0 0) 0 0)

(subst-if-not 0 (lambda (x)
                  (or (listp x)
                      (eq 'quote x)))
          '(1 '(2 3 4) '(5 6 7) 8 9))
;=> (0 '(0 0 0) '(0 0 0) 0 0)
```

Comment: I knew there was a simpler way, I looked at `(subst-if) earlier, but didn't know how to have "all/every" element as the test condition.

Comment: @Ash well, subst operates on the tree, so it's recursing into the car and cdr of each cons cell.  The trick is that `listp` doesn't actually check for a proper list but just "cons cell or nil".  Those are the only things in your case that you *don't* want to replace.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong?

You have actually done a good work with `loop` and it works! Remember that `'` stands for `quote`, so:

```
'(1 '(2 3 4) '(5 6 7) 8 9)
```

is equal to

```
(quote (1 (quote (2 3 4)) (quote (5 6 7)) 8 9))
;       |  |      | | |    |      | | |   | |
       (0 (0     (0 0 0)) (0     (0 0 0)) 0 0)
```

you see, your quotes have been substituted too (except for the first one, which has been consumed during evaluation of the function argument)! One quote is enough to suspend execution.

Comment: The use of `loop` here is actually overkill, though.  Using the standard subst-if, this is just `(subst-if '0 (complement #'listp) '(1 (2 3 4) (5 6 7) 8 9)) => (0 (0 0 0) (0 0 0) 0 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize that `'foo` is syntactic sugar for (quote foo), so when you use quotes inside an already-quoted list, this:

```
'(1 '(2 3 4) '(5 6 7) 8 9)
```

evaluates to this:

```
(1 (quote (2 3 4)) (quote (5 6 7)) 8 9)
```

So when you substitute all the list elements with 0, you get:

```
(0 (0     (0 0 0)) (0     (0 0 0)) 0 0)
```

You either need to not put extra quotes in your examples, or you need to handle the quote operator specially in subs-list:

```
(defun subs-list (list value)
  "Replaces all elements of a list of list with given value"

  (loop for elt in list
       collect
         (cond 
           ((listp elt) 
             (subs-list elt value))
           ((eq 'quote elt)
             elt)
           (t
             value))))
```

Comment: This can be handled more concisely with `subst-if`, even with the special handling of the quotes.