# In clojure, why doesn't "some" function work consistently on collections?

Tags: list, clojure, lisp

For below, why does the last one return a nil? Function "some" doesn't work on list of lists?

```
(some #(= % 1) '(1 3)     )  ; ==> true
(some #(= % '(1 3)) ['(1 3) '(1 2 3)]    )  ; ==> true
(some #(= % '(1 3)) '('(1 3) '(1 2 3))   )  ;==> nil
```

Comment: '(1 3) =/= '(quote (1 3))

Comment: Have a look at [Replace elements in nested quoted lists adds new elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24370500/1281433).  The symptoms are different in that case, but the explanation of what `'(... '(...) ...)` means is what you need, and it's included there.

Comment: Also, try (note double quotation): `(some #(= % ''(1 3)) '('(1 3) '(1 2 3)))`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should modify the expression like this:

```
(some #(= % '(1 3)) '((1 3) (1 2 3))   )
=> true
```

You already quoted the list by using `'`, you don't need to quote again in the quoted list.

You can easily check what happened in REPL:

```
user=> '((1 3) (1 2 3))
((1 3) (1 2 3))
user=> '('(1 3) '(1 2 3))
((quote (1 3)) (quote (1 2 3)))
```

Answer (score 2):

@Kevin

I see @ntalbs answered but I am in the habit of testing various timings. You may be curious to note the time difference I observed:

```
(time (some #{'(1 3)} '((1 3) (1 2 3))))      ;0.073
(time (some #(= % '(1 3)) '((1 3) (1 2 3))))  ;0.632

(time (nil? (some #{'(1 3)} '((1 3) (1 2 3)))))     ;0.068
(time (nil? (some #(= % '(1 3)) '((1 3) (1 2 3))))) ;0.628
```

If you are processing large amounts of data this may be a useful knowledge

Comment: Thanks @Frank! This is quite useful.  What would be the rational for using "nil? " as part of function? I don't see much performance difference on my machine.

Comment: Got it! "nil?" returns true or false

Answer (score 2):

As ntalbs points out, the issue here is double quoting. It may be a better idea to use vectors instead of lists, or build lists with `list`. Both would save you some confusion and vectors have different performance characteristics (near constant random access time).

```
(some #(= % '(1 3)) [[1 3] [1 2 3]])
(some #(= % '(1 3)) (list (list 1 3) (list 1 2 3)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but why does (= [1 3]'(1 3)) evaluate to true? Vector same as list??

Comment: Because they're both sequences. Docs for = say: "Same as
Java x.equals(y) except it also works for nil, and compares
numbers and collections in a type-independent manner"