# Lisp, nested every statements

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a function that can determine if a list of list contains only numbers. for example '( '(1 2) '(3 4) ) => t while '( '(1 2) '(3 x) ) => nil. I can not get my code to work and would appreciate any help! I have been using every. Is this the best approach? Here is my code so far.

```
(defun list-all-numbers(l)
  (every #'numberp l))

(defun list-of-list-numbers(l)   
  (every #'list-all-numbers l))
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but you may find some of the discussion in [Replace elements in nested quoted lists adds new elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24370500/1281433) useful.  Your code is fine, but your data is `((quote (1 2)) (quote (3 4))`, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions work well:

```
? (LIST-OF-LIST-NUMBERS '((1 2) (3 4)))
T
? (LIST-OF-LIST-NUMBERS '((1 2) (3 x)))
NIL
```

but the problem is that you use excessive quoting in your example:

```
?  '( '(1 2) '(3 4) )
('(1 2) '(3 4))
? (car '( '(1 2) '(3 4) ))
'(1 2)
? (caar '( '(1 2) '(3 4) ))
QUOTE
```

but you simply want

```
? '((1 2) (3 4))
((1 2) (3 4))
? (car '((1 2) (3 4)))
(1 2)
? (caar '((1 2) (3 4)))
1
```