# Lisp list manipulation issue

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, cdr

I have this expression ,

```
(write (cdr (car' ('(p q) r))))
```

http://ideone.com/bkZv20

which gives `((P Q))` as the output . I've been scratching my head all day and am still unable to figure out how this works .

Doing just the `car` part gives,

```
(write (car' ('(p q) r)))
```

gives `'(P Q)` .

Then , according to me `(cdr '(P Q))` should give `(Q)` as the output .

How is the final answer , `'(P Q)` is my question .

Comment: What is this mystery `car'` function you seem to be using? Do you really mean to use `'` to quote twice?

Comment: I recieved the expression that way ! Have a look at the link ,

Comment: I think you might find the answers to [Replace elements in nested quoted lists adds new elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370500/replace-elements-in-nested-quoted-lists-adds-new-elements) helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra quote (the first one is stuck to the `car` but still parses correctly) in there which causes a quoted quote, so what you essentially have is:

```
(write (cdr (car '((quote (p q)) r))))
```

Taking the `car` of this leaves you with just the data:

```
(quote (p q))
```

And again taking the `cdr` of this results in the data:

```
(p q)
```

As you observed. If you look at the car of the car instead with

```
(write (car (car '((quote (p q)) r))))
```

you should see the

```
quote
```

itself. Remember that `'(a b)` and `(quote (a b))` are the same thing, and the printout from whatever you're using might show either form.

So what you want to do is just remove the extra quote, i.e.:

```
(write (cdr (car '((p q) r))))
```

Comment: But what is the reason I get that answer ?

Comment: I edited the first code snipped a bit, can you see what happens now?

Comment: could you please break down the flow (result at each step) ? would make it easier to understand . thanks .

Comment: I think that's as simple as I can put it now.

Comment: Another small question if you dont mind - when `car` of a list is taken where `quote` exists as an entity, we take the first 2 values instead of just the first . Is this true ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. `car` always takes the first element of a list, regardless of what it contains.